# How to set min and max value for range (d3 rangeSlider)

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3 rangeSlider I want to set min and max values for the range picker.

here's the link to the package : https://rasmusfonseca.github.io/d3RangeSlider/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/RasmusFonseca/d3RangeSlider), the first two arguments to the `createD3RangeSlider` function are the min and max values. For example, `createD3RangeSlider(0, 10, "#slider-container")` would set the min value to 0 and the max value to 10. `createD3RangeSlider(50, 60, "#slider-container")` would set the min value to 50 and the max value to 60.